# Reliable shortcut for non-ASCII text insertion

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator, automation, auto-complete

I occasionally use text strings such as `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Unfortunately, I don't have a `¯` or a `ツ` on my keyboard, so using such strings can be a bit of a pain, usually involving a web search and copy and paste. I'd prefer to have an easier way of typing these. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Set up a text replacement in System Preferences.

   - Problem: It does nothing in several apps such as Discord and Firefox.
2. Set up an automator service running this AppleScript:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       tell application "System Events" to keystroke "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"

   end run
   ```

   - Problem: It outputs `¯\_(a)_/¯`
3. Set up a different automator service which

   ```
   1. Get Contents of Clipboard
   2. Set Value of Variable "clipboard"
   3. Get Specified Text "¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
   4. Copy to Clipboard
   5. Run AppleScript `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down`
   6. Get Value of Variable "clipboard"
   7. Copy to Clipboard
   ```

   - Problem: Sometimes it does nothing, sometimes it pastes the original clipboard contents, sometimes it will actually paste `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. Adding 0.2 second pauses both before and after step 5 did not fix the problem.

And with that, I've run out of straightforward, reasonably simple ideas that have a chance of having a return on investment somewhere in the vicinity of their cost. Web searches haven't really produced anything other than BetterTouchTool, which is a route I'd prefer not to take at this time.

**Is there a reasonably simple, free, reliable, and legal method of doing what I want to do?**

I'm running 10.14.6, on a Mac with a Touch Bar. Touch Bar only solutions are generally acceptable, though solutions that can work with or without the Touch Bar are preferable.

Comment: Perhaps a custom keyboard layout would make sense.   https://software.sil.org/ukelele/

Comment: Create a text file that stores the symbols you want?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the several text shortcut apps that are out there in the world.

aText (https://www.trankynam.com/atext)

Typinator (https://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/)

Just as a couple of examples.

Comment: That's not what the Typinator page says... "When you use Typinator in other applications, it will display a registration reminder after a couple of expansions.".  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I missed part of that, sorry. +1

Answer (score 0):

`keystroke` seems to only support ASCII characters, but we can do it with the clipboard:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set textBuffer to "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
    repeat with i from 1 to count characters of textBuffer
        set the clipboard to (character i of textBuffer)
        delay 0.05
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end repeat
end tell
```